# how to add the buttons to the popover view in ipad app

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

i want to add some text fields and the buttons to the popover view ...

how to add those and i hav to read the text added into text field by user later ...

....should i need seperate view controller class to control popover view or can i control with existed one which calls popover view....

any help Appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIViewController using IB or programatically. Add needed buttons, textfields and maybe some logic there and use this viewController for initializing an UIPopoverController (as Gendolkari suggested).

Answer (score 0):

The UIPopoverView is created by passing in a ViewController which controls the content of your popover. Check out the `initWithContentViewController:`, this allows you to pass your own ViewController. That ViewController would have a view with the text fields and button that you want.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button addTarget:self 
        action:@selector(aMethod:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[self.tableView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: certainly not what asked by the user here